# How can I test all inputs at one time on form validation, prevent the default submission and add classes on the inputs in the best manner

Tags: javascript, html

I am looking for the best way to test all of my inputs at the same time, prevent the form submission and display my border-color: red on each input. Any help would be appreciated.

```
btn.addEventListener('click', () => {
    if (title.value.length == 0) {
        title.classList.add('notValid');
        e.preventDefault();
    }
    if (author.value.length == 0) {
        author.classList.add('notValid');
        e.preventDefault();
    }
    if (pages.value.length == 0) {
        pages.classList.add('notValid');
        e.preventDefault();
    }
});
```

Comment: Hi there! Your code should be working. What seems to be the problem?

Comment: My code will prevent the default submission and will submit but when I do not put in values for two of the inputs ,only the first input will take the class and if I dont put any input in, only the first input will turn red